# Z-axis auto adjusting fixture device

Tags: design, mechanical

I am looking for a mechanism that would allow me to support a fixture attached to a 3-axis motorized stage. I have attached a picture of my current design. I trying to design/incorporate some sort of hardware that will support the green fixture to travel in the z-axis as the grey stage moves during its analysis procedure. I originally tried a lab top scissor lift but that requires me to manually adjust the stage. I was thinking of a gas spring platform but wasn't sure how to incorporate it properly. Any ideas?

[image: fixture example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Z-Axis auto adjusting fixture](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18515/z-axis-auto-adjusting-fixture)

Comment: Rephrased the question and attached image link. Not a duplicate

Comment: Same basic question though...

Comment: Instead of reasking, edit the original question with this phrasing (if you believe it is better) and with the image.

Comment: I don't get the questions, without more explanation and specifications; Can you clarify? Why do you need a gasspring platform?
(Reading the question, i would just use bolts and make the holes matching or use an adapter plate.)

Comment: @SolarMike I deleted the previous question so there shouldn't any more issue on it.

Comment: @SimpelenLeuk I am trying to find either a piece of hardware or a design to support the weight of the fixture (in green) so that I do not put a load greater than 3kg on the motorized stage (in gray). Some sort of mechanism that will allow the fixture to articulate in the z-axis (as the x and y axis are already covered by securing the fixture to the stage using the four screw holes at each corner).

Comment: Let me see if I understand. Grey thing is an automatic positioning stage. The problem is that the grey thing cannot hold the weight of the green thing.  You want to somehow add a support on the green thing, presumably on the right side of the picture, to take some of the load so that the grey thing does not take all the load.  The problem with that is that the support has to move, because the green thing is moving.  Do I have the problem stated correctly?  If so, what is the range of travel / how much does it move, what is the total load, and how much of the load do you need to support?

Comment: @DanielKiracofe yes you nailed it perfectly. The maximum travel in the Z-axis is 6 inches. The total load that can be supported by the grey stage is 3kg. The X/Y travel is minimal (less than an inch).

Answer (score 0):

A normal spring will not work, because as you move it, the force changes.  Beyond a certain point, the force will get so high that your positioning stage has to fight the spring, i.e. the spring will be making the load on the stage higher, not lower.  What you want instead is called a "constant force spring". As the name says, it will exert a constant force over a fairly wide range of motion.  For example

- https://www.leespring.com/learn-about-constant-force-springs
- http://www.vulcanspring.com/conforce-constant-force-springs
- http://www.centuryspring.com/constant-force

and many other manufacturers as well.